# Laravel middleware to skip route group

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have the following routes file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'foo.only'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'FooController@index');
    Route::get('/about', 'FooController@about');
});

Route::get('/', 'BarController@index');
Route::get('/about', 'BarController@about');
```

In my FooOnlyMiddleware handler I have something like:

```
public function handle($request, $next)
{
    if ($foo == true) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else {
        // skip the entire route group and move onto the next route
    }
}
```

How do I do this so that if `$foo = false` it will skip the entire route group and move onto the `bar` routes?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, as both of your `foo`  and `bar` routes are the same:

```
Route::get('/', 'FooController@index');
Route::get('/', 'BarController@index');
```

The `bar` route will never be reached.

Here is one way to accomplish the conditional routes you want:

Your routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'foo.only'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'FooController@index');
    Route::get('/about', 'FooController@about');
});

Route::get('bar/', 'BarController@index');
Route::get('bar/about', 'BarController@about');
```

FooOnlyMiddleware:

```
public function handle($request, $next)
{
    if ($foo == true) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else {
        return redirect('/bar/'.$request->route()->uri());
    }
}
```

Of course, this would be valid if every route using the FooOnlyMiddleware, has an equivalent `bar` route. Otherwise, just redirect to any route you want.

Comment: @crabby the question was how can he ignore the **entire** route group as soon as a single route fails the conditional.

Comment: I understood your question. However, you are defining the same route twice. That won't work.